# Error when using Google's protobuf

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

```
#include <google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h>
namespace google::protobuf::io

....
int fd = open("myfile", O_WRONLY);
ZeroCopyOutputStream* raw_output = new FileOutputStream(fd);
CodedOutputStream* coded_output = new CodedOutputStream(raw_output);
```

The above is following the tutorial [here](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.coded_stream.html), but when I compile get the following errors:

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'io'
```

What can be wrong here?

**UPDATE**

When I changed the above to `using namespace google::protobuf::io;` I get a new error saying the symbol `FileOutputStream` is not defined, how come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you mean

```
using namespace google::protobuf::io;
```

Answer (score 2):

In response to the updated question about why FileOutputStream is not declared...

I think you need

```
#include <google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl.h>
```

Per the docs:

http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.zero_copy_stream_impl.html

> This file contains common implementations of the interfaces defined in
>   zero_copy_stream.h which are only included in the full (non-lite)
>   protobuf library.
>
> These implementations include Unix file descriptors and C++ iostreams.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h>
namespace google::protobuf::io
```

This is ill-formed. You need to be `using namespace google::protobuf::io;`, I'm guessing from the rest of the posted code.

How come is that the code segment for the top is for that header only, and the tutorial depends on the whole library. You're just copy and pasting code without even understanding it. I'm not going to sit here and debug every error you could possibly come up against. You will have to actually read the library pages and know C++ first.

Comment: How come is that the code segment for the top is for that header only, and the tutorial depends on the whole library. You're just copy and pasting code without even understanding it. I'm not going to sit here and debug every error you could possibly come up against.